# C# HttpClient API without parameters

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to access an API from a link
mysite.....api/market/goods/sell?game=csgo&goods_id=921424&min_paintwear=0.000&max_paintwear=0.001
but the result comes ignoring the parameters like:
mysite.....api/market/goods/sell?game=csgo&goods_id=921424
How can I fix it?

My code look like: mysite is mask of real site

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 Stream str = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://mysite.....api/market/goods/sell?game=csgo&goods_id=921424&min_paintwear=0.000&max_paintwear=0.001");
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str);
 string line;
 while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     if (line.Contains("paint"))
         Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
 str.Close();
```

Comment: Does server want parameters in the URL (after the question mark). as HTTP headers, or in the body of the request (usually json)?

Comment: Does that endpoint of that api even support these parameters? And how do you know they are being ignored?

Comment: yes, its work in browser, but not work in code. I can check result by link in browser

Comment: They are probably checking the client string or a header value.